# Can the Defensive Duelist feat be used at the same time as the Uncanny Dodge Rogue feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, rogue, reactions

I'm making a Bladesinger (Wizard)/Swashbuckler (Rogue) Multiclass.

Can the Rogue's Uncanny Dodge class feature be used at the same time as the Defensive Duelist feat?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, you need to choose one or the other

Each of them uses your reaction, which is a part of the "action economy" for a round/turn in D&D 5e.  You get one reaction each round; choose which one of these you want to do: the Defensive Duelist feat, or the rogue's Uncanny Dodge.

The [Defensive Duelist](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/defensive-duelist) feat (PHB, p. 165) says:

> When you are wielding a finesse weapon with which you are proficient
> and another creature hits you with a melee attack, you can use your
> reaction to add your proficiency bonus to your AC for that att⁠ack,
> potentially causing the a⁠ttack to miss you.

The rogue's [Uncanny Dodge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#UncannyDodge) feature says:

> Starting at 5th level, when an attacker that you can see hits you with an attack, you can use your reaction to halve the attack’s damage against you.

You can only take one [reaction](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Reactions) until the start of your next turn:

> When you take a reaction, you can’t take another one until the start
> of your next turn. If the reaction interrupts another creature’s turn,
> that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction. ([Basic Rules, "Reactions", p. 73](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=73))

#### When should you choose which?

If you are pretty sure that a slight boost in AC will render the hit a miss, use that one.  Zero damage is better than half damage.

If a boost in AC won't stop it being a hit, use the class ability to halve the damage.

Comment: "You get one reaction on another creature's turn" - Reactions aren't limited to other creatures' turns. You could use it on your own turn if the trigger for that reaction occurs (e.g. you get hit by an opportunity attack as you move).

Comment: @V2Blast Yeah, fixed that, good catch.